# Adjectives relating to town and city names

Tags: adjectives

A person who lives or was born in London may be called a Londoner; a person in Dublin, a Dubliner.

In this way, which formal (non colloquial) adjectives correspond to citizens of the following cities,

- York
- Carlisle
- Edinburgh
- Kent
- Brighton
- Oxford
- Cambridge
- Bath
- Whitby

Comment: Many towns don't have derived nouns like *Londoner,* although there are *Brightonians.* Kent is not a town and has *Men of Kent* (East Kent) and *Kentish Men* (West Kent) -- [Wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Kent)

Comment: To add to Andrew Leach's observation *Many towns don't have derived nouns*, theoretically, it is probable that there is a noun but that it is never used in current English and that alternatives also occur. It seems to have been the case that larger towns had such names and, for no particular reason, various adjectives and nouns were coined for smaller ones but did not survive into popular use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambridge is 'Cantabrigian', and Oxford 'Oxonian'.

Oxford Dictionaries does not include 'Oxfodian' as meaning 'a resident or native of the City'. But it has other meanings, such as a 'member of the Oxford movement of 1833.

Other than those answered by Andrew Leach in his comment I don't believe any of the others lend themselves to adjectival use in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Which are other common word suffixes for derived nouns, in addition to -er for Londoner or -ian for Cantabrigian ?

Comment: A former pupil of Harrow School is known as an 'Old Harrovian'. I have seen the ending applied to other places ending '..ow', e,g Padstow - Padstovian. Again they all end in '...ian', but a resident of Manchester is a 'Mancunian', of Norwich a 'Norvicensian', and of Liverpool,  a  'Liverpudlian'. If I think of a different ending I will let you know!

Comment: It doesn't come up on a search but I might be tempted to call a native of York a Jorvician. 'York' is derived from the Viking name 'Jorvic'.

Comment: @user3189923 No I'm afraid that wouldn't work with 'York'. Besides a 'Yorker' has another meaning to do with cricket.